# Change the \crefrange title once

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, german

I'm using `cleveref` and want to use `\crefrange` in a German sentence but it doesn't create the correct title for this case:

> In den Abschnitte 7.3.1 bis 7.3.3 wurde für den […]

```
In den \crefrange{subsec1}{subsec2} wurde für den […]
```

How can I change the title (or is it called label?) once?

*edit*:
My desired output would be the following:

> In den Abschnitte*n* 7.3.1 bis 7.3.3 wurde für den […]

But only for this one instance. Usually the default output is correct.

Comment: And what do you like the new text to look like? Which is exactly the desired output?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Totally forgot that. I edited the post.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and welcome to TeX.SX! I've provided an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do it but wouldn't that (changing  single occurrence) introduce inconsistency in your document?. In any case, you can provide a redefinition using `\crefname` and keep the redefinition local by grouping (see the extra pair of braces in my answer). In the example below, the first cross-reference shows the modified label and the second one uses the default label:

```
\documentclass[german]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{6}% just for the example
\chapter{Test chapter}
\setcounter{section}{2}% just for the example
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection one}
\label{subsec1}
\subsection{Test subsection two}
\subsection{Test subsection three}
\label{subsec2}


In den {\crefname{section}{Abschnitte}{Abschnitten}\crefrange{subsec1}{subsec2}} wurde für den […]

\crefrange{subsec1}{subsec2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sweet! Thanks. I didn't think about just putting braces around that section.

What do you mean by inconsistency?